# Is there a way to continue in a Flag when there is no $OPTARG set in Bash, GETOPTS?

Tags: bash, scripting, flags, continue, getopts

I would like to build a script with getopts, that continues in the flag, when an $OPTARG isn't set.
My script looks like this:

```
OPTIONS=':dBhmtb:P:'
while getopts $OPTIONS OPTION
do
        case "$OPTION" in
                m ) echo "m"          
                t ) echo "t"     
                d ) echo "d";;     
                h ) echo "h";; 
                B ) echo "b";;
                r ) echo "r";; 
                b ) echo "b"                                 
                P ) echo hi;; 
                    #continue here                    
                \? ) echo "?";;
                :) echo "test -$OPTARG requieres an argument" >&2
                         
        esac
done
```

My aim is to continue at my comment, when there is no $OPTARG set for -P.
All I get after running ./test -P is :
`test -P requieres an argument`
and then it continues after the loop but I want to continue in the -P flag.
All clear?
Any Ideas?

Comment: It will help if you can provide a short description of the behavior that you want to implement when you see the '-P' flag.

Comment: The '-P $OPTARG' flag should initialize a Variable, but when the -P $OPTARG isn't set, the script should look for an other Varible which isn't set in the loop and when both of them not initialized then the script should exit.

Comment: Strongly recommend you don't put much logic into the case branches: merely set variables, and then the logic for setting default values or other error cases (for example you can specify at most one of -a or -b or -c) should be coded after the options have been processed.

Comment: Can you give me an example?

Comment: `then it continues after the loop but I want to continue in the -P flag` What does it mean to "continue in the -P flag"?

Comment: As I said above, the script could exicute  the -P in 2 differnt ways. The first way is that a $OPTARG is set while running ./test -P (OPTARG). The second way comes up, when there is no Argument set. Then it should check if a other Variable is set, if it is, then the script continues, if not then the script should exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, fix the missing `;;` in some of the case branches.

I don't think you can: you told getopts that `-P` requires an argument: two error cases

1. `-P` without an argument is the *last* option. In this case getops sees that nothing follows -P and sets the OPTION variable to `:`, which you handle in the case statement.
2. `-P` is followed by another option: getopts will simply take the next word, even if the next word is another option, as OPTARG.

   Change the case branch to

   ```
   P ) echo "P: '$OPTARG'";;
   ```

   Then:

   - invoking the script like `bash script.sh -P -m -t`, the output is

     ```
     P: '-m'
     t
     ```
   - invoking the script like `bash script.sh -Pmt`, the output is

     ```
     P: 'mt'
     ```

   This is clearly difficult to work around. How do you know if the user intended the option argument to be literally "mt" and not the options -m and -t?

You might be able to work around this using `getopt` (see [the canonical example](https://salsa.debian.org/debian/util-linux/-/blob/master/misc-utils/getopt-parse.bash)) using an optional argument for a long option (those require an equal sign like `--long=value`) so it's maybe easier to check if the option argument is missing or not.

---

Translating `getopts` parsing to `getopt` -- it's more verbose, but you have finer-grained control

```sh
die() { echo "$*" >&2; exit 1; }

tmpArgs=$(getopt -o 'dBhmt' \
                 --long 'b::,P::' \
                 -n "$(basename "$0")" \
                 -- "$@"
        )
(( $? == 0 )) || die 'Problem parsing options'
eval set -- "$tmpArgs"

while true; do
    case "$1" in
       -d)  echo d; shift ;;
       -B)  echo B; shift ;;
       -h)  echo h; shift ;;
       -m)  echo m; shift ;;
       -t)  echo t; shift ;;
      --P)  case "$2" in
               '')  echo "P with no argument" ;;
                *)  echo "P: $2" ;;
            esac
            shift 2
            ;;
      --b)  case "$2" in
               '')  echo "b with no argument" ;;
                *)  echo "b: $2" ;;
            esac
            shift 2
            ;;
       --)  shift; break ;;
        *)  printf "> %q\n" "$@"
            die 'getopt internal error: $*' ;;
    esac
done

echo "Remaining arguments:"
for ((i=1; i<=$#; i++)); do
    echo "$i: ${!i}"
done
```

Successfully invoking the program with `--P`:

```sh
$ ./myscript.sh --P -mt foo bar
P with no argument
m
t
Remaining arguments:
1: foo
2: bar
```

```sh
$ ./myscript.sh --P=arg -mt foo bar
P: arg
m
t
Remaining arguments:
1: foo
2: bar
```

This does impose higher overhead on your users, because `-P` (with one dash) is invalid, and the argument must be given with `=`

```sh
$ ./myscript.sh --P arg -mt foo bar
P with no argument
m
t
Remaining arguments:
1: arg
2: foo
3: bar
```

```sh
$ ./myscript.sh --Parg mt foo bar
myscript.sh: unrecognized option `--Parg'
Problem parsing options
```

```sh
$ ./myscript.sh -P -mt foo bar
myscript.sh: invalid option -- P
Problem parsing options
```

```sh
$ ./myscript.sh -P=arg -mt foo bar
myscript.sh: invalid option -- P
myscript.sh: invalid option -- =
myscript.sh: invalid option -- a
myscript.sh: invalid option -- r
myscript.sh: invalid option -- g
Problem parsing options
```

Comment: 1. Sorry for the missing ";;" in the case branch, of cource I didn't forgot these. 2. Looking at the example does not help me, maybe because of I´m new at this. Could you try to explain it a bit closer with my comment above?

Answer (score 0):

- Do not mix logic with arguments parsing.
- Prefer lower case variables.

> My aim is to continue at my comment, when there is no $OPTARG set for -P

I advise not to. The less you do at one scope, the less you have to think about. Split parsing options and executing actions in separate stages. I advise to:

```
# set default values for options
do_something_related_to_P=false
recursive=false
tree_output=false

# parse arguments
while getopts ':dBhmtb:P:' option; do
        case "$option" in
                t) tree_output=true; ;;
                r) recursive="$OPTARG"; ;;
                P) do_something_related_to_P="$OPTARG"; ;;
                \?) echo "?";;
                :) echo "test -$OPTARG requieres an argument" >&2
                         
        esac
done

# application logic
if "$do_something_related_to_P"; then
    do something related to P
    if "$recursive"; then
        do it in recursive style
    fi
fi |
if "$tree_output"; then
    output_as_tree
else
    cat
fi
```

Comment: Ok, I understand that want you do, but the Problem is that this thing above is just a cutout of a big script and I want to avoid, to put commands and the end of the loop, because of the -P option is just one of many and when I will run the Script with an other Flag the script always execute these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Example of "don't put <strike>programming</strike> application logic in the case branches" -- the `touch` command can take a `-t timespec` option or a `-r referenceFile` option but not both:

```sh
$ touch -t 202010100000 -r file1 file2
touch: cannot specify times from more than one source
Try 'touch --help' for more information.
```

I would implement that like (ignoring other options):

```
while getopts t:r: opt; do
    case $opt in
        t) timeSpec=$OPTARG ;;
        r) refFile=$OPTARG ;;
    esac
done
shift $((OPTIND-1))

if [[ -n $timeSpec && -n $refFile ]]; then
    echo "touch: cannot specify times from more than one source" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

I would **not** do this:

```sh
while getopts t:r: opt; do
    case $opt in
        t)  if [[ -n $refFile ]]; then
                echo "touch: cannot specify times from more than one source" >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            timeSpec=$OPTARG ;;
        r)  if [[ -n $timeSpec ]]; then
                echo "touch: cannot specify times from more than one source" >&2
                exit 1
            fi
            refFile=$OPTARG ;;
    esac
done
```

You can see if the logic gets more complicated (as I mentioned, exactly one of -a or -b or -c), that the case statement size can easily balloon unmaintainably.

Comment: Is it possible that I can use your 2nd example too? I need it in these in the Option.

Comment: You have 2 experienced people telling you "don't do it", but you're the one who has to live with the results. And of course the poor people who will have to maintain it when you've moved on.